# NameError when using super() in enum constructor

Tags: python, python-2.7, enums, super, nameerror

I am using Python 2.7.10 with the `enum34` library. I am trying to do the following:

```python
from enum import Enum


class Foo(Enum):
    def __init__(self):
        pass


class Bar(Foo):
    VALUE = 1

    def __init__(self, value):
        super(Bar, self).__init__()
```

When this code is run, I receive the error `NameError: global name 'Bar' is not defined`. Could someone help explain why I receive this error and if it's possible to call the parent constructor of an enum subclass? Thank you in advance!

Edit: Traceback (with path names redacted) for Olivier Melançon:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../test.py", line 9, in <module>
    class Bar(Foo):
  File "/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/enum/__init__.py", line 236, in __new__
    enum_member.__init__(*args)
  File "/.../test.py", line 13, in __init__
    super(Bar, self).__init__()
NameError: global name 'Bar' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: I don't think this works even in Python 3.4+. IIRC, subclassing enum classes only works when only the base class has behavior and only the subclasses have enumeration members.

Comment: I want to add that I get the same error in Python3 if I provide the class and object to super, but not if I just call super()

Comment: What is the intention of this code? Why do you want to override the initializer of `Enum` in `Foo` to do nothing, and why do you want to override it in `Bar` to take a value and ignore it?

Comment: Traceback posted for @OlivierMelançon.

Comment: Anyway, I'm pretty sure the cause of this is that `Bar.VALUE` has to call `__init__` before `Bar` is stored in the name `Bar`. And having a chain of classes where only the leaf defines members and only the non-leafs add methods is probably legal and functional. So, could you define a `class Baz(Bar)` to hold the `VALUE`, while leaving the `__init__` override in `Bar`? Or would that not meet whatever your goal is?

Comment: @abarnert, you can assume that there is some other behaviors attached to the init functions that are unessential for the purpose of this question.

Comment: `super()` uses the `__class__` cell, so the fact that the metaclass's code runs before `Bar` is added to the namespace doesn't matter.

Comment: @user9027325 If you're trying to do something that isn't documented to work, and in fact doesn't work, and I can't assume anything other than that there was "some behavior" you wanted, I can't tell you how to achieve that. I could at best explain why your code doesn't work (and I think it's exactly what I said in my last comment) and then leave you to come up with a different design. Is that what you're after?

Comment: @user9027325:  I figured out how to make the `super()` call work -- check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57178871/208880).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Bar.VALUE.__init__` is being called before `Bar` exists.

You can see where this happens in [`EnumMeta.__new__`](https://bitbucket.org/stoneleaf/enum34/src/f24487b45cd041fc9406d67441d2186ac70772b7/enum/__init__.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#__init__.py-235), but even without looking at the code, it pretty much *has* to work this way: the whole point of an `Enum` class is that its enumeration members are constant values that act as attributes of the class while also being instances of it.

In that, this code will produce the exact same error in 3.4+ with the stdlib `enum` module, and similar errors with multiple third-party `enum` replacements.

In general, if you have Enum hierarchies at all, you're expected to put values only in the "leaf" classes and behavior only in the non-leaf classes. However, the only restriction that's actually explicitly documented in [Restricted subclassing of enumerations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#restricted-subclassing-of-enumerations) is no values in non-leaf classes, so technically what you're trying to do should be legal, even if it's unusual and was never explicitly intended to work.

---

If you were using Python 3, there's a pretty easy workaround: just using `super()` instead of `super(Bar, self)`, and it doesn't matter than `Bar` doesn't exist yet.

In Python 2, since that isn't doable, you need to manually simulate `super`. For full generality, that means writing the code to walk the `mro` and so on, but since multiple inheritance including two or more `Enum` classes isn't going to work anyway, you'll be fine just hardcoding it statically:

```
def __init__(self, value):
    Foo.__init__(self)
```

---

Alternatively, if you change your design to put all the behavior in non-leaf classes, that will also work:

```
class Foo(Enum):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self, value):
        super(Bar, self).__init__()

class Baz(Bar):
    VALUE = 1
```

---

Most likely, whatever you're actually trying to accomplish could be done in a better way without requiring either of these changes. But since your toy example doesn't accomplishes anything, there's nothing more to show.

Comment: Yes, `__new__` and `__init__` are both called when the members are created, which is before the class officially exists.

Comment: @EthanFurman It seems like anyone who might wonder about `__new__` would know that it must be getting called before `__init__` even without scanning the code, right? But maybe what's going on is complicated enough that it's worth mentioning? I honestly don't have an intuition on that; if you think I should mention `__new__`, I'll edit the question (or you can edit it, of course).

Comment: @EthanFurman Also, your "the class officially exists" seems like slightly clumsy terminology, but the way I phrased it in the answer (just end-running around the problem by referring to the name `Bar` instead of the class…) seems even worse. Any suggestions for a better way to put it?

Comment: It's actually very clumsy terminology.  A better explanation is that the name `Bar` is not bound to the class until after the metaclass finishes processing the class, but unlike normal Python classes where instances are created and initialized /after/ class processing and creation, `Enum` members are created and initialized /before/ the class has been fully processed.  The magic `super()` in Python 3 may not have this problem, I haven't tested that.

Comment: @EthanFurman Yeah, I was looking for a way to say that in one short sentence that's better than what I have in the answer, but maybe there is no way to do that. Meanwhile, the magic `super` doesn't have this problem, because `__class__` is a closure cell that gets created as part of executing the class definition. See [creating the class object](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#creating-the-class-object) or [PEP 3135](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/) for details. But I can see why you wouldn't have tested that, because this is an odd use case.

Answer (score 0):

To work around the problem of the name `Bar` not yet being bound to the `Bar` `Enum` when it's members are being created, use:

```
super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
```

(note that `self.__class__` has taken the place of `Bar`)